# React-Stars can't be combined with FontAwesome Icons in Firefox and IE

Tags: reactjs, firefox, font-awesome

I try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stars in combination with an icon from FontAwesome. This works well in Chrome and Safari, but the icon is rendered over the `span` containing the star in Firefox which results in the star not being clickable. There is a small area above and under the star that can be clicked in Firefox.

What can I do to fix this?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactStars from 'react-stars'
import '../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ReactStars
                    size={50}
                    half={false}
                    onChange={(newRating) => {
                        console.log(newRating)
                    }}
                    char={<i className="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: react-rating works with font-awesome 4
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Comment: @JeGe That's why it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stars#api they expect `char` to be string. So i guess thats the problem that its not working as expected when using elements.

I search and found this library `react-rating` which seems pretty cool and ease to use. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating

You can find their examples here:
http://dreyescat.github.io/react-rating/

You can add `font-awesome` icons just as easy as:

```
<Rating
  emptySymbol="fa fa-star-o"
  fullSymbol="fa fa-star"
  fractions={2}
/>
```

Comment: It does not work in the codesandbox link, clicking the middle of the icon will not select it.

Comment: @AnnaIraHurnaus just updated my answer. I guess you need to use another library since that one does not support elements inside `char`

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting react-rating, that's exactly what I needed :-D